# How to get rid of unwanted horizontal line at y=0?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[notice how there's a horizontal line at y=0 but it's not in my legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWgxw.png)

Here's my code:

```
datelist2 = [str(x) for x in datelist]

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in datelist2]

figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=150)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval = 5))

for i in range(1, 10):
    y = pushdf.iloc[:, i]
    plt.legend(loc = 'best')
    plt.plot(x, y, label = pushdf.columns[i])

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Weight (lb)")
plt.title("Push Progression")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

For some reason, there is a horizontal line at y=0 with a color that isn't in the legend and is very obviously not part of my data. This also appears on 2 other graphs that I have made and the code is essentially identical. I just want to get rid of this line.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Please provide runnable code. For example `datelist` is missing

Comment: why do you think this line is not part of your data: you plot 9 lines (`for i in range(1, 10)`) and there are 9 lines, including the one at y=0 on your chart.

Comment: most probably the column header for this line starts with a `_` so it's not shown in the legend

Comment: Just call `plt.legend(loc = 'best')` once after the for loop and you will see the 9th line appear in your legend.